# Can't connect to virtualbox postgreSQL from host using navicat

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, database, postgresql

I am currently trying to set up some databases using PostgreSQL 9.4 on a guest VM using VirtualBox running centos 6.5. I'm trying to connect to the database using navicat from the host but all it's giving me is a message saying:

could not connect to server: Connection refused(0x000274D/10061) Is the server running on host '192.168.0.97' and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

I've set the postgresql service up to listen for "*" hosts and made sure it's listening on the default 5432 port. I've set it to allow 0.0.0.0/0 on md5. I've also set the network adapter for the VM as bridged. I also tried disabling the firewall to see if that would help but it did not work. And for the record I did try to restart the postgreSQL as well. Though the VM is still getting connectivity to the internet and is able to ping the host machine. Looking from other posts all told me to do the above that I just listed but nothing works.

Any ideas?